# Seesaw like animation in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I want an animated UIView that will move like this lever on this image. [seesaw](http://moon.ouhsc.edu/dthompso/balance/seesaw.gif) but i have no great knowledge on animations in xcode. I can only do sliding like this

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:2.0 options:(UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
animations:^
    {
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        self.bug.center = CGPointMake(75, 200);
    }
        completion:^(BOOL finished)
        {
            NSLog(@"Move to left done");

        }
 ];
```

Is there a way that i can use manipulate this code and animate it like a seesaw?

Comment: Recall a new animateWithDuration: in your completion block (where you have your NSLog)

Comment: Do you know how to rotate a view using a transform and how to autoreverse (an possibly repeat) an animation?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist no :( so sad :(

Comment: start by looking at things like `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle)` and `UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse`